# How do I place multiple NOT conditions inside of a cfif statement?

Tags: coldfusion, logic, cfml

This is my code:

```
<cfif (CFFILE.FileSize GT (4194304))>
Delete File
<cfelseif CFFILE.serverFileExt neq "png"  >
Delete File
<cfelse>
It's ok
</cfif>
```

I want to add "jpg" and "jpeg" as allowed file types. I tried, this w/o success.

```
<cfif (CFFILE.FileSize GT (4194304))>
Delete File
<cfelseif ( ( CFFILE.serverFileExt neq "png" ) OR ( CFFILE.serverFileExt neq "jpg" ) OR ( CFFILE.serverFileExt neq "jpeg" ) ) >
Delete File
<cfelse>
It's ok
</cfif>
```

Any ideas?

**SOLUTION:**

My OR statement needs to be an AND, thank you Miguel-F, and with Busches improvment, this is the final result:

```
<cfif (CFFILE.FileSize GT (4194304))>
    Delete File
<cfelseif NOT ListFindNoCase("jpg,jpeg,png", CFFILE.serverFileExt)>
    Delete File
<cfelse>
    It's ok
</cfif>
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Use and instead of or

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is syntactically correct but the logic is flawed. That condition will always be true because you are using `OR`.  As soon as one of the conditions is true the condition passes.  Try using `AND` instead, like this:

```
<cfif (CFFILE.FileSize GT (4194304))>
    Delete File
<cfelseif (CFFILE.serverFileExt NEQ "png") AND (CFFILE.serverFileExt NEQ "jpg") AND (CFFILE.serverFileExt NEQ "jpeg")>
    Delete File
<cfelse>
    It's ok
</cfif>
```

See Busches answer for a way you can condense your code a bit if you use the ColdFusion [ListFindNoCase()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6d80.html) function.

Comment: While his problem is not using `AND`, I'd also recommend him to switch to `! ListFind( "png,jpg,jpeg", cffile.ServerFileExt )` instead of writing the same conditional over and over again.

Comment: @Busches write that up as an answer. Easier to read and maintain. I'd vote it up

Comment: I updated my answer with an example, but if @Busches adds it as an answer I will remove it from mine.

Comment: Miguel-F I did per @Travis's suggestion.

Answer (score 9):

As Miguel-F stated, your issue is you need to use `AND` instead of `OR`. I'd also recommend, in cases like these, to switch to using `ListFindNoCase()` instead of using multiple `OR/AND` statements.

```
<cfif CFFILE.FileSize GT 4194304> <!--- You also don't need all those () here --->
    Delete File
<cfelseif NOT ListFindNoCase( "png,jpg,jpeg", cffile.ServerFileExt )>
    Delete File
<cfelse>
    It's ok
</cfif>
```

The `ListFindNoCase` is a lot more concise and easier to read and maintain.

Comment: I would use `ListFindNoCase` instead to ignore case SeNsiTiVITy.

Comment: +1. List functions are usually more readable once you get beyond two values/conditions.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem in your code is simply the use of "OR" in your  statement. If I read your sample correctly, it's going to delete the file every time.

I believe this will have the effect you're looking for.

```
<cfelseif ( ( CFFILE.serverFileExt neq "png" ) 
       AND ( CFFILE.serverFileExt neq "jpg" ) 
       AND ( CFFILE.serverFileExt neq "jpeg" ) ) >
```

You're not looking for a situation where the potentially-deleted file satisfies any *one* of the conditions (which is what "OR" does), because any file extension will be unequal to at least 2 of your 3 options.

Rather, you're looking for a situation in which the potentially-deleted file satisfies *all* of the conditions (which is what "AND" does.